# enforce projection rules for queries

Tags: mongodb

is there a way to basically enforce a projection rule for all queries on a collection? So for example, if I have a collection `widget`, is there a way to make sure that a field `secretAttribute` if present in the document is not returned in the query by default unless the query `projection` explicitly asks for it. Kind of opposite of like how `_id` is automatically projected unless the projection parameter explicitly rejects it. So for example I may have a `widget` document:

`{ _id: '51a4e3962dfff00105000009', name: 'foo', color: 'white', status: 'open', secretAttribute: 'bar' }`

if I do `db.widget.find({color: 'white'})` it will return the document but without `secretAttribute` visible:

`{ _id: '51a4e3962dfff00105000009', name: 'foo', color: 'white', status: 'open' }`

I would have to explicitly ask for `secretAttribute` in the `projection` argument to `find()`:

`db.widget.find({color: 'white'}, {name:1, color:1, status: 1, secretAttribute: 1})` to get it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this currently.  If it's a field that's large and *usually* not needed, you might consider storing it in a separate collection (requiring a second read when you do want it, but it might be an overall saving of resources depending on how big it is, etc).

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is not possible currently. In my application, I keep a lighter version of my objects in memcached. For example, in this case, you could create a widgetLite object and keep it in memcache, the object might have only id, name, color and status. In most cases, you would need to retrieve just the widgetLite object and taking it from memcache will be extremely fast and will result in much less number of db queries, thus giving you better performance.